# how to add background music each and every image in scroll view in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application i am keeping some images in scroll view.Here if i scroll images for each image i need to get one background music.If there are images like elephant,rat, cat.if elephant image is came when it is scrolled some background music like elephant sound   should come.if rat is there some different music like rat sound  should come.please suggest me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

using below code you can make your requirement, for more details you can refer this [**LINK**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.music);
mp.start();
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wud say you should use gallery view for this and then in the callback listener method "onItemSelectedListener" you can know which element is in the view now and then create your Media Player instance there as told by @Mansi Vora in the above post.
*MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.music);

mp.start();*
If you wanna use the scroll view any ways, then you must know how much it has been scrolled and whic element is on the view now.
Then add the background music to it.